# How to get nav in bootstrap 3 running under xPages to show the active page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to create an application in xPages using bootstrap 3 instead of using the bootstrap4xpages extension library.

How do I dynamically have a nav show the active page in xPages? I would like to use the nav as a custom control.

Alternatively I guess I could style the existing application navigator with bootstrap styles to get the same functionality.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: the `styleClass` attribute of components can be computed, and so can attributes of passthru tags.

Comment: I have tried "reverse engineering" the navigator to use the bootstrap themes using the styleclass. Basically trying to wrap the nav and the pagetreenodes or apply styles to the nav to get the correct results. Maybe I should take a look at the bootstrap4xpages extension library and see how they accomplished the same thing. I have also tried using js to compute the correct active page but its a lot of manual work. The extlib just made things too easy...

Comment: I have used the same CSS approach with different projects. Changing traditional HTML components like div's to xpages components in order to get the value computed. For example this progress tracker was easy to modify so that it shows active for when it matches the status field. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1982#issuecomment-7814657 had some thoughts about doing an openNTF project on something similar; could be a cool custom control I use progress trackers on all workflow projects now and this just drops right in.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a component to compute an attribute. For example, this is perfectly valid: `<ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li class="#{javascript:return isHomePage ? 'active' : '';}"><xp:link value="/" text="Home" /></li></ul>`

Comment: The default renderer for the page navigator component sends markup that caters to OneUI; essentially, all that the bootstrap4xpages library does is define a whole slew of new renderers and override the `rendererType` for all applicable components if the theme is applied. That library targets Bootstrap 2, but the markup structure for navs didn't change a whole lot in 3, so in theory you could copy the renderer and the theme rules for just the page navigator to your NSF and it should work as is... if not, it wouldn't require much tweaking to conform to the v3 markup syntax.

Comment: The November release of the Bootstrap4XPages plugin already targets Bootstrap 3 (as well as v2.3). It uses the standard 'selection' attribute to highlight the active menu option. Install the plugin and the ExtLib sample database on your server, set the theme of that database to 'bootstrapv3.0.0' to see an example.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Somehow I missed that update.

Comment: I missed that update too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was asked a while back and somehow I missed it. But if you are still using your manual implementation of bootstrap 3, then I suggest using a repeat control for your menu items or do them manually and compute the style class as Tim suggested. In order to provide a more detailed answer we need more information about your use case and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think computing the style class is the best way to accomplish it. I didn't think of a repeat for the nav though. I like using the ext library. But knowing how to do things the hard way makes you appreciate the easy ways... thanks for the response!